# BackboneJS .get() and .at() undefined after .fetch()

Tags: backbone.js, collections, get, undefined

localhost:3000

```
[{"idrooms":1,"roomname":"red","occupants":0},    {"idrooms":2,"roomname":"green","occupants":0},{"idrooms":3,"roomname":"blue","occupants":0},   {"idrooms":4,"roomname":"yellow","occupants":0},    {"idrooms":5,"roomname":"purple","occupants":0},{"idrooms":6,"roomname":"cyan","occupants":0}]
```

On the client side I started with the basics I know so far:
                
                
                
                    
                    Title

```
            <script src="jslib/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="jslib/underscore.js"></script>
            <script src="jslib/backbone.js"></script>
            <script>
            // Your code goes here
            var Room = Backbone.Model.extend({
                defaults: {
                idrooms: 0,
                roomname: "default",
                occupants: 0
                }
            });

            var RoomList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: Room,
                url: 'http://localhost:3000'
            });

            var roomlist = new RoomList();
            roomlist.fetch();

            console.log(roomlist);
            console.log(roomlist.at(1));
            console.log(roomlist.get(1));
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

There is all kind of data in roomlist and if I drill into it I see the attributes of all six Room model objects. roomlist.at(1) and roomlist.get(1) are returning an undefined. Perhaps I made a mistake somewhere.

The server is short enough perhaps I should post it:

```
            var express = require('express')
              , cors = require('cors')
              , get = require('./routes/get')
              , http = require('http')
              , path = require('path')
              , mysql = require('mysql')
              , app = express();

            var connection = mysql.createConnection({ host: 'localhost', user: 'root',  
                                                      password: 'oilwell123', database: 'multiroomchat'});

            app.get('/', cors(), function(req, res, next){
                if (connection) {
                    connection.query('select * from rooms', function(err, rows, fields) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        res.contentType('application/json');
                        //res.write(JSON.stringify(rows));
                        res.send(rows);
                        res.end();
                    });
                }
            });

            app.listen(3000, function(){
              console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80');
            });
```

jsonlint says its valid json...

Thank you for posting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fetch` method is asynchronous, so the output variable won't have been assigned by the time you use it.

Try this.

```
roomlist.fetch({
    success : function(collection, respone) {
        console.log(collection);
        console.log("collection.at(1)", collection.at(1));
        console.log("collection.get(c0)", collection.get("c0"));        
    }
});
```